# In a TV Series, I heard an actor say 'Love' as in British |o| Job and not Love as in |la|, is it a British Dialect or something?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, slang, informal-language, accent

Yet, when I looked it up in the dictionary, the word 'love' is pronounced the same either in British or American Accent. Thank you & Have a lovely day!

Comment: BrE = Luv or Southern BrE Lav. AmE = lurve … but then I'm Northern BrE, so I'm biased  ;-)

Comment: If you can tell us who said it and in what, we might be able to narrow it down.

Comment: @Tetsujin  Is that a typo? There’s no ’r’ in AmE *love*

Comment: @Jim There is to a Brit, quite clearly - it's a bit of a joke, in fact & is often spelled that way to emphasise it's supposed to be said in a bad American accent.

Comment: Ok well I don’t get it. There is absolutely not even a hint of an r in AmE that you could even pick at as a joke.

Comment: That's the difference in the accent; one hears it clearly, the other doesn't. I heard someone the other day, in a similar vein, claim they had "no accent". I had to laugh.

Comment: do you hear it in any of these? http://www.forvo.com/word/love/#en

Comment: I hear it to some extent in 2, 3 & 5, but almost to the joke-point I mentioned above in 6 & 7. [My partner wondered what the heck I was doing, btw ;) - as an aside, 4 sounds British, not Australian, to me.

Comment: @Tetsujin Of course, phonetically there's no r-coloring in any of those recordings.  In AmE accents like mine or Jim's, we pronounce most of our /r/ sounds, including in that position, so of course we have trouble perceiving an /r/ unless it's actually present phonetically.  It's only natural that we can't hear it as *lurve*.

Comment: @snailboat - it's likely very similar to the UK joke phrase, "There's no R in glass" - the extended length of the vowel makes 'short-vowel' users hear an r.

Comment: I heard it in The Blacklist :) Thank you very much

Comment: Blacklist hmm?... which character/episode/approximate timestamp? I have both seasons here already & can easily have a look

Comment: It is season 1, episode 9 almost at the end of the episode. He said "Hello, Love".

Comment: Geordie accent - Newcastle, UK [or at least an attempt at one - hard to tell from 2 sentences, but 'threat is down' sounds like Geordie to me]

Comment: Thank you, you definitely answered my question, now I know it is a British Accent or a dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm British and I can tell you that there are huge differences in the way a word as simple as "love" can be pronounced by different British people, especially those with strong regional accents. More generally you have to accept with English pronunciation that there is a wide range of acceptable pronunciation nowadays and that we are more tolerant of variation today than in the past.

Comment: There is a general rule of thumb that when you study languages, historical units of measurement, genes etc., the diversity of any specific subclass tends to be greatest in/around the region of origin. Human genomes and human languages are most diverse in Africa, English dialects are most diverse in England, dialects of Romance are most diverse in Italy, pre-metric units of weight referred to as *pound* were also most diverse in Italy, alphabets are most diverse around the Middle East, and so on.